# Why won't my Python console be cleared with system('cls')?

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, cls

This code won't work for me:

```
import os

print('cls method')
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

print('chr method')
print(chr(27) + "[2J")
```

Output:

(pasting the log directly deletes "|?|")

```
cls method
|?|chr method
```

Comment: On which OS are you working?

Comment: Win 10. I know 'cls' is enough, this is ctrl+v'd to make sure I have not missed anything.

Answer (score -1):

bro you just need to type in python console:-

```
import os
os.system('cls')
```

Comment: Does not work:

import os
print('Hi')
Hi
os.system('cls')
Out[4]: 0

Comment: @MBee `Out[4]: 0` you're using jupyter (ipython) just do `cls` or `%cls`